# How to force Mathematica to interpret a file as HTML?

Tags: import, internet

Some web pages do not explicitly contain the file extension "html" but is formatted that way (like [this one](http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/transfers.sd?season_id=142&team_id=142&teamTabs=transfers)). If I saved this page to my computer then Mathematica could parse it correctly. But if I just write `Import[sdURL, "Data"]`, it returns weird stuff. How could I force mathematica to interpret the ".sd" page as HTML? Thanks!

Comment: `Import["http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/transfers.sd?season_id=142&\
team_id=142&teamTabs=transfers", {"HTML", "Data"}]` gets what you want, I think.

Comment: @bobthechemist Oh thanks! I was just digging through the help file and the manual to `Import` but did not find that usage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect this is in the documentation, but just in case it is not obvious, one can indicate the import format as the first element of an array in the 2nd argument to `Import`:

```
Import["http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/transfers.sd?season_id=142& team_id=142&teamTabs=transfers", {"HTML", "Data"}]
```